# Dataingestion with Flume & Hadoop doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

I'm using Flume 1.4.0 and Hadoop 2.2.0.
When I'm starting Flume and writing to HDFS I get following Exception:

```
(SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:460)] process failed
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$RenewLeaseRequestProto overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2562)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2572)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1427)
        at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateClassFile(ProxyGenerator.java:426)
        at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateProxyClass(ProxyGenerator.java:323)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass(Proxy.java:521)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getProxy(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:92)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProtocolProxy(RPC.java:537)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNNProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxies.java:328)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:235)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:510)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2433)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2467)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:287)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.doOpen(BucketWriter.java:207)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.access$000(BucketWriter.java:53)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.run(BucketWriter.java:172)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.run(BucketWriter.java:170)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.runPrivileged(BucketWriter.java:143)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.open(BucketWriter.java:170)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.append(BucketWriter.java:364)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink$2.call(HDFSEventSink.java:729)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink$2.call(HDFSEventSink.java:727)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The part of my hdfs-sink in the flume.conf is looking like this:

## Define a sink that outputs to hdfs

```
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = memory-channel
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:8020/flume
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollCount = 10
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.batchSize = 10
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollSize = 0
```

I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody has the same problem, here's the solution:

Replace all older jars in the flume/lib-directory by copying the newer ones from hadoop.

Comment: where do I find those jars?